# Rolling shutter effect

Tags: modifiers, camera, effects

Is it possible to create an artificial shutter effect in blender to render something like this?

[image]

Comment: When meshes are placed next to each other and parented they look connected.  Then the child can be moved independently.  Also there is [child of] constraint with an influence value.  Both of those concepts can be searched at BSE.  The famous video site that rhymes with noonoob may have tutorials on these topics. Many images appearing on a monitor can be considered artificial or not.

Comment: This effect is produced by the camera sampling each frame 1 line at a time, so if the frame is 1080 pixels high and the object moves fast enough it will be composed of 1080 (1 pixel high) frames per image, all stacked on top of each other. Theres a great way to recreate this effect below!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everything in Blender is *artificial*. (lighting, shading, ...)

Blender Cycles has the rolling shutter functionality. Go to the scene settings and enable **motion blur**. In the *Shutter Type*, select **Top To Bottom**. Make sure to choose a relatively large shutter time and a small *rolling shutter duration*.

[image]