# Limitation of a Rolling Shutter effect for propeller

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, keyframes, interpolation

I am trying to create artifacts of a spinning propeller using cycles from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115755/rolling-shutter-effect).
I have the propeller animated using 2 keyframes starting at 0 degrees, and ending at 80000 degrees over few frames.

However Blender seems to interpolate the frames using closest rotation, which means, that when the propeller rotates more than 180 degrees per frame, the effect will reverse.
But I need it to spin multiple times per frame, to create that authentic effect.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit far-fetched, but maybe it helps anyway.

You could perhaps do it with trickery. There is an awesome video by Matt Parker, where he explains how to fake this effect using real footage: https://youtu.be/nP1elMR5qjc
Crucially, this can apply the effect to much slower footage.
Maybe you can use it for your endered footage as well, if you render it out on a slow timescale (quasi oversampled).
He even provides code for the video processing in  the video description, so it would be easy to try?

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, and yes, that would work, but I want to make an entire animation utilizing this effect. Is there any easier way to do that?